# Can get only one textbox value using isFormField() for enctype="multipart/form-data" forms submittion

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have to fetch multiple textboxes values along with an image to a servlet. Here I can get value of only First Textbox textbox and for 2nd textbox it prints the value of first textbox only not it's individual value...

```
   FileItem fileItem = it.next();
boolean isFormField = fileItem.isFormField();
if (isFormField) {
String fldname=fileItem.getFieldName();                
System.out.println(fldname);
if(fldname.equalsIgnoreCase("txt")){
String ffname = (String)fileItem.getString();
System.out.println("tx 1"+ffname);  if(fldname.equalsIgnoreCase("txt2"));
String txt2 = (String)fileItem.getString();System.out.println("tx2"+txt2); }
```

I need values of all the textboxes but here I can get only 1.

Comment: first you have to use list to store all the parameters coming from your httpServlet request and then use them .

Comment: i am able to get one value without storing them in list....but not other one

Comment: because the request is consumed by first param. hence use list to store data